# How to open / hover to submenu items using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a menu like

```
<li class="main-menu">
  <a accesskey="a">menu item 1</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a accesskey="d">submenuItem1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu">
      <a accesskey="e">submenuItem2</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="innermenu"><a >innerMenuItem1</a></li>
        <li><a>innerMenuItem1</a></li>
        <li><a>innerMenuItem2</a></li>
        <li><a>innerMenuItem3</a></li>
        <li><a>innerMenuItem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How to hover / show submenu when main menu item selected and when submenu selected show innermenu items. am very new to jquery have some issues in do this esspecially submenu to inner menu.Thank you..

Comment: So what are your specific issues and what have you tried?

Comment: @span, what you know, what exactly you understand. Do you think without trying myself some ask you. If you dont understand correctly th reason to ask, better ignore and move ahead.

Answer (score 0):

`accesskey` actually only works in conjunction with the <kbd>alt</kbd> key, we can intercept the general keydown event and handle the hotkeys that way. If we intercept the keydown and it is one of the keys, we want to toggle the `.active` class on the relevant `li`. Then use CSS to hide and display the submenus based on hover/class status.

My example below uses a `data-key` attribute to set up the attributes, on page load we extract the keys and associated elements into an array. This array is scanned and acted upon when `keydown` is handled.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/8S8qL/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="main-menu">
<li data-key="65">
  <a>menu item 1 (a)</a>
  <ul>
    <li data-key="68">
      <a>submenuItem1 (d)</a>
    </li>
    <li data-key="69">
      <a>submenuItem2 (e)</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>innerMenuItem1</a></li>
        <li><a>innerMenuItem1</a></li>
        <li><a>innerMenuItem2</a></li>
        <li><a>innerMenuItem3</a></li>
        <li><a>innerMenuItem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li ul {
    display:none;
}

li:hover > ul,
li.active > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

**JS**

```
var keys = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-key]').each(function () {
        keys.push({
            key: $(this).attr('data-key'),
            elem: $(this)
        });
    });
});

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (e.keyCode == keys[i].key) {
            keys[i].elem.toggleClass('active');
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In fiddle seems to be working fine, but the same code when i use in sample html page to see results, an error message "object expected" at line of statement,$(document).ready(function () {